# How to get Featured image from the Post Link using Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

In my wordpress project, I have set of links for inner pages. And all these pages have featured images. These links to inner pages are generated using wordpress menu feature.

What I want to do is, when someone clicks on these links, then without loading the full page and by using Ajax call, I want to fetch featured image of that Page on that URL and display that image on same page. I have already created a code using jQuery to read the URLs into a variable, so that we can use them some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know how to run the AJAX call, you'll want your .php file to output the path to the featured image. Wordpress has built in functions to retrieve the featured image, but the tricky part is being able to use those functions via AJAX.

You'll want your php file to look something like this

```
<?php//get-image.php 
//file that gets called from $.post(), $.get(), or $.ajax() function
//first load up wordpress
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');//assuming get-image.php resides in /themes/yourtheme/ajax/
//get the post id
$post_id = url_to_postid($url_sent_from_ajax);
//now get the featured image
$image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id , 'post-thumbnail' );
echo $image_url;
?>
```

Then your ajax return function can do what it wants with image URL

Hope this helps