# Get featured images from internal WordPress links

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, shortcode

I want to create lists of internal posts and pages in the post editor and display their featured images. Is it possible?

I assume I'll have to transform the post URL to a post ID to then get the featured image, but I don't know how to do that. (It seems similar to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486290/how-to-get-featured-image-from-the-post-link-using-wordpress).)

Comment: why?just loop through the links and do it?

Comment: @FastSnail the links would be written manually, not by a loop, would it be possible?